# Cannot redirect .exe output to file

Tags: windows, command-line, redirection

I'm trying to capture a program's output and then write it to a file.

Running `MyFile.exe -args > foo.txt` gives an empty file. The same goes for `MyFile.exe -args > foo.txt 2>&1`. If I run the command as usual, `MyFile.exe -args`, the output is clearly written to the console.

The program is written in C++ and writes using `wprintf_s`. It seems to append a newline on the last line, if that matters.

I'd appreciate any ideas on how to get this to work. If anyone cares to reproduce: [the file I'm using](https://github.com/DanStevens/AudioEndPointController/blob/master/Release/EndPointController.exe) and [its GitHub page](https://github.com/DanStevens/AudioEndPointController/) ([VirusTotal report](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/0285ec156f1bf2aea57c8c74e4779855784203efd8141159b6ba04249a8035f9/analysis/)).

Comment: Are you using bash as a replacement for cmd.exe or for psh ?

Comment: @Hennes Sorry, I meant cmd.exe. Haven't used Windows in a while so a terminal is bash for me :-).

Comment: @Psycogeek: That's fine, we can figure out workarounds. What's far more interesting is, why and how is this EXE behaving this way, and how to redirect its output to a file?

Comment: @Psycogeek Adding the arguments after the path didn't help, good idea though. Yes, the idea is to parse the output to detect which device got removed/added during an interval. It's probably possible to detect this some other way (the APIs seem to be private though), but this made me curious.

Comment: A quick test shows that **C:\temp>dir /d >dir.txt** works as expected (but using **-d** does not since dir expects a slash to mark arguments, unlike your program). You might experiment with quotation marks around the file name and/or args.

Comment: Cleaned those comments, a search shows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000655/why-cant-i-get-the-output-of-a-c-program-using-process-in-c stack overflow question , that has similarites. aparentally it could be changed to work that way?

Comment: Interesting indeed. I'll modify the source and report with how it went; however in the future I'd be good to have a solution for when one cannot modify the source code.

Comment: @Karan Flushing the output did the trick. Would indeed be interesting to have a way to accomplish this without modifying the source in the future.

Comment: @Zar: Same here. I too am interested to know if there's any way at all to get the output of the unmodified EXE to redirect successfully to a file.

Comment: @Zar: FWIW two years later out of curiosity I just ran the same EXE on Win10 1607 and `EndPointController.exe -a > Test.txt` worked absolutely fine. Perhaps it was a Windows bug that was subsequently fixed?

Comment: @Karan I think previously you needed to do `cmd.exe /c EndPointController.exe -a > Test.txt`, which doesn't make sense why it could launch cmd.exe with redirected handles but not that executable

Answer (score 0):

You can written it to a script file and redirect the output to the desired file

for example: **echo "MyFile.exe -args" > file.sh**

then try to execute the script file and move the output and error of a file to the text file which you need

ie) **sh file.sh >foo.txt 2>&1**

This will work! and it will write the output as well as error of the executable file (.exe file) in the seperate text file.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. The question is asking about Windows command line not bash